# Save data from http request into an array, to send it as json back to the client

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a node.js server that does an API request, the page should send as response the data I get from that api.
The catch here is:

I need to do several calls to the api, put all the data together separated by an id e send that back as json to the client.

To create that request I have first to query my DB and get the data I have to send to the api
After that I filter that data using array.filter
and to create the requests, I am using array.map to call a function that deals with the request.

Code:

```
router.get('/', cors(),  (req, res) =>{

    const response =  getListOfStatistics()
 });
```

when I enter the page, the function `getListOfStatistics()` is fired:

```
function getListOfStatistics(){
    axios.get('http://localhost:4002/')
    .then(response =>{
        items = response.data
        let result = filterStatistic(items)
        return result;
        //I wrote that return result when trying to give the data back
        //So I could send it to the client as json

    })
    .catch(err =>{
        console.log(err)
    })
```

}

After getting the data from the db, I try filtering it:

```
function filterStatistic(items){

const jahreStatistic = items.filter(item => item.period == 0)
const virtelJahrStatistic = items.filter(item => item.period == 3)

//Both methods above are working

jahreStatistic.map(item => {
    connection.statistic_id = item.statistic_id
    var periods = getReportingPeriod(item.period)
    for(let i=0; i < 3; i++){
        switch(i){
            case 0:
            connection.reporting_period = periods.prevYear
            preOrderedObjects.Jahr =  sendHTTPRequest(item)
            break;
            case 1:
            connection.reporting_period = periods.actualYear
            preOrderedObjects.Jahr =   sendHTTPRequest(item)
            break;
            case 2:
            connection.reporting_period = periods.nextYear
            preOrderedObjects.Jahr =   sendHTTPRequest(item)
            break;
         }
        }
    })
}


function  sendHTTPRequest (item){

request.post({
    headers: {'content-type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
    url: 'https://externalapi/api/', 
    form: connection
    },
    (err, response, body) => {
        if(response.headers['x-status'])
        {
            info.name = item.name
            info.evas = item.evas
            info.id = item.statistic_id
            info.link = item.link
            info.resourceID = response.headers['x-resourceid'];
            info.fileName = response.headers['x-filename'];

            console.log(info.name) //This shows that my three requests 
            were made.

            **if(item.period==0){
                //Evas is a global array evas = []
                //info is a global object info = {}
                evas.push(info)
                //My goal was to push each request to this array and 
                //return it to after, add to another object.
                //This does not work.
                return evas**
            }else{
                ids.push(info)
                preOrderedObjects.Jahr = ids
            }
            }
    }) 
}
```

I would like to get all the data pushed to the evas array
and then added to my preOrderedObjects.Jahr

After, at the end, I want to return that to the client as json

Anyone has an idea of what I am missing and how to maybe fix that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to convert your `getListOfStatistics` function into a [callback function](https://codeburst.io/javascript-what-the-heck-is-a-callback-aba4da2deced) . You are making a GET request to another server using [promises](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/promises) (we can say a better version of callbacks) and the result might take a while to have a value.

The callback will return the `result` variable once it has a value.

```
function getListOfStatistics(callback){
    axios.get('http://localhost:4002/')
    .then(response =>{
        items = response.data
        let result = filterStatistic(items)
        callback(result);
    })
    .catch(err =>{
        console.log(err)
    })
}
```

To execute `getListOfStatistics`, you will need to pass a function as a parameter, like this:

```
let response;
getListOfStatistics(function(result)){
    response = result;
}
```

**Note** that `response` must be a variable and it will have a value once the callback is finished.

Same goes for `sendHTTPRequest` method, you will need to convert it too since you want all requests to finish. However using `Evas` and `preOrderedObjects` as global variables don't look like a good idea, but anyways.

```
function filterStatistic(items, callback){

const jahreStatistic = items.filter(item => item.period == 0)
const virtelJahrStatistic = items.filter(item => item.period == 3)

//Both methods above are working

jahreStatistic.map(item => {
    connection.statistic_id = item.statistic_id
    var periods = getReportingPeriod(item.period)
    for(let i=0; i < 3; i++){
        switch(i){
            case 0:
            connection.reporting_period = periods.prevYear
            sendHTTPRequest(item, function(result){
              preOrderedObjects.Jahr =  result
            })
            break;
            case 1:
            connection.reporting_period = periods.actualYear
            sendHTTPRequest(item, function(result){
              preOrderedObjects.Jahr =  result
            })
            break;
            case 2:
            connection.reporting_period = periods.nextYear
            sendHTTPRequest(item, function(result){
              preOrderedObjects.Jahr =  result
            })
            break;
         }
        }
    })
}


function  sendHTTPRequest (item, callback){

request.post({
        headers: {'content-type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
        url: 'https://externalapi/api/', 
        form: connection
    },
    (err, response, body) => {
        if(response.headers['x-status'])
        {
            info.name = item.name
            info.evas = item.evas
            info.id = item.statistic_id
            info.link = item.link
            info.resourceID = response.headers['x-resourceid'];
            info.fileName = response.headers['x-filename'];

            console.log(info.name) //This shows that my three requests 
            were made.

            **if(item.period==0){
                evas.push(info)                
                callback(evas)
            }else{
                ids.push(info)
                preOrderedObjects.Jahr = ids
            }
         }
    }) 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, for starters you can try to change the request headers to: 'application/json'.

As for the requests, they are async, so you cannot get the result immediately, you can turn the getListOfStatistics into a callback or call the async/await trick on the function as follows:

```
function getListOfStatistics(){
    axios.get('http://localhost:4002/')
    .then(async (response) =>{
        items = response.data
        let result = await filterStatistic(items);

        return result;
    })
    .catch(err =>{
        console.log(err)
    });
```

As for that switch/case, you are also making http async requests, you can use the async await method OR you can push the requests into a promise array and resolve them all at once:

```
let requests = [];

jahreStatistic.map(item => {
    connection.statistic_id = item.statistic_id
    var periods = getReportingPeriod(item.period)
    for(let i=0; i < 3; i++){
        switch(i){
            case 0:
            connection.reporting_period = periods.prevYear
            requests.push(sendHTTPRequest(item));
            break;
            case 1:
            connection.reporting_period = periods.actualYear
            requests.push(sendHTTPRequest(item));
            break;
            case 2:
            connection.reporting_period = periods.nextYear
            requests.push(sendHTTPRequest(item));
            break;
         }
        }
    })
}

Promise.all(requests).then((results) => {
 // do some work here
});
```